# How to render a field in a Views' PHP code field?

Tags: views

in a view, I would like to render the field `$data->field_field_video[0]` in a PHP code field.
It seems that it contains all the information needed to be formatted but how can I output in the HTML ?

```
 [rendered] => Array 
    ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
                [#theme] => image_style 
                [#path] => public://video_embed_field_thumbnails/vimeo/58413545.jpg 
                [#style_name] => square_thumbnail-100 [#children] =>  [#printed] => 1 )    
      ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  print drupal_render($data->field_field_video); 
?>
```

Comment: It outputs nothing.

Comment: You will need print. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information of new visitors, data contains field_ as suffix in original field. So field_name will be rendered using

```
<?php
 print drupal_render($data->field_field_name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of the rendering one of the view pages where you list custom fields of different article types is using the `$view->render_field()` function.

```
<?php print $view->render_field('field_your_field_name', $row_number);?>
```

based on your example it should look like this:

```
<?php print $view->render_field('field_video', $row_number);?>
```

as it is declared in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view%3A%3Arender_field/7.x-3.x).

If you use `drupal_render()` or `render()` functions, it works in 7.50, but you will get a lot of warnings in 7.54.

Comment: Where's the `$row_number` coming from?